# Seaborn: edges in distplot don't fit the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

When using matplotlib and seaborn in Jupyter with Python 2.7.12, I noticed that the edges of the distplot I drew don't fit the plot correctly (cf. the 2 figures below). At first I thought it was an issue with the code, but when trying the same code on someone else's laptop with the exact same versions of Jupyter and Python, the issue did not occur. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

wrong plot:

[image: wrong plot]

right plot:

[image: right plot]

I would gladly share the notebook with the code and the dataset, but since I am kind of new to sharing notebooks online, I do not know what the 'standard way to go' is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This would have nothing to do with python or jupyter. You need to check for the versions of seaborn and scipy (and possible statsmodels(?)). Apart, you need to share a [mcve] within the question (not with some huge notebook file).

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the difference between the two plots is the bandwidth of the kernel used to calculate the KDE. Maybe there are different default values on both machines.

Try to play with either the `bw=` or `kernel=` parameters ([documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html#seaborn.kdeplot)). Like so:

```
fig,(ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1, figsize=(5,10))
x = np.random.randn(100)
sns.distplot(x, ax=ax1)
sns.distplot(x, kde_kws={'bw':5}, ax=ax2)
```

[image]